Who's "Above all"?
 One of my kind is

 ? ? ? ? ? G ? ?

 Another one of my kind is

 ? ? R ? ?
 
 Yet another one of my kind is
 
 ? ? ? E 

 Yet, yet another one of my kind is
 
 ? ? T A ? ? ? 

Together we are...(take help from the subtle hint above). Tell me who I am... the answer is 12 letters long... have in mind, I am "Above all".


Together you are...

 The Great Lakes, a series of five interconnected lakes on the US-Canada border.

The clues point us towards...

 their names: MICHIGAN, HURON, ERIE and ONTARIO, with the missing fifth member being the 12-letter LAKE SUPERIOR, a word literally meaning 'above all'.

There was another clue beside the title:

 The 5 letters shown in the correct places in the names spell out 'GREAT' when rearranged! (This was what originally put me on the right track, prompting me to think of groups of five described as 'Great' - the rest followed...)


Correct, well done!
